# Get current value of a textbox in codeigniter on keyup event

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Hi I'm currently learning about the AJAX in jQuery and now I'm trying to use it in codeigniter. Now what happen is that I have a textbox wherein on keyup event it will call the function on my controller and it's working anyways but the controller itself doesn't get the current value of the textbox and it remains blank since I haven't submitted the form yet so it can't get the POST data. Well I don't want to submit the form either since I only have one shot for submit and what I only want for this one is to check whether the event is already existing or not (for validation purposes). Here's my code so far with added comments for better viewing.

View:

```
<div>
<form>
<table border="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <title>Name: </title>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="name" type="text" name="eventname" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <div id="name1"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $base; ?>javascripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js">
     </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $base; ?>javascripts/ajax.js">
     </script>

</form>
</div>
```

The controller:

```
<?php

class Login extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('test_model');
    }

    public function view()
    {
        $data['base'] = $this->config->base_url();

        //CHECK IF THE $PAGE VIEW IS EXISTING
        if ( !file_exists('test/views/pages/test_form/test_form.php'))
        {
            // IF PAGE DOESN'T EXISTS SHOW 404 ERROR
            show_404();
        }

        //FOR THE TITLE PART
        $data['title'] = ucfirst('Test'); 

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('pages/test_form/test_form', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);

    }

    public function message()
    {
        //this one will access database
        echo $this->test_model->check_event($this->input->post('eventname'));
        //username doesn't get the current value on keyup unlike the AJAX part
    }

}
```

The model:

```
<?php
class Test_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function check_event($test_input)
    {
        if($test_input==null){
            return "True";
        }
        else
            return "False";
    }

}
```

and the AJAX:

```
$('#name').keyup(function() { //LISTENER FOR BUTTON CLICK BASED ON ID button ON THE PHP PAGE
    var name = $('#name').val();

    $.ajax({ //STARTS AJAX
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/CodeIgniter_2.1.3/index.php/login/message/', //THIS PAGE IS LOADED ON THE AJAX data IS THE CONTENTS ON THE PAGE NOTE COMMA SEPARATED VALUES
    data: 'name='+name,
    statusCode: { //THE STATUS FOR THE PAGE. NOTE THIS IS CASE SENSITIVE
        404: function(){ //IF 404 ERROR OCCURS THIS MESSAGE WILL BE DISPLAYED
            $('#name1').text('Page not found');
        }, //NOTE COMMA SEPARATED VALUES
        202: function(){ //IF 202 SHOW THIS TEXT
            $('#name1').text('Please wait');
        }
    }, //NOTE COMMA SEPARATED VALUES
    success: function(data){ //IF PAGE EXISTS OR FOUND THE data FROM THE GIVEN PAGE WILL BE LOADED AND PASSED
        $('#name1').html(data); //THE content ID ON THE PHP PAGE WILL CONTAIN ALL THE html data OF THE GIVEN PAGE
    }
    });
});
```

Well sorry for this AJAX part. it's full of comments which I don't think necessary It's just a note for me to quickly review the codes. :) Is there's something wrong with my codes or do I need to use some function to retrieve the data?

Comment: `$this->input->post('name')` and NOT 'eventname'. Just basic debugging. And those comments are eye sore to be honest. Atleast small letters are prefered.

Comment: Well sorry for not being clear about my question, edited so it can comply somehow. 

@itachi well I'm not an expert on this one, I'm just studying it for future purposes and I thought I should use the name I specified on the input haha! Also for the comments, it's for my personal and learning use and I love those eyesores so that I'm required to read it everytime I go back with my codes since as you said it's totally an eye sore even for me. :)

Comment: `name` attribute is important for POST request. A few notes. `Success()` is deprecated as of jquery 1.8.2 and will be removed in future release. Use `.done()` instead. Refer to manuel for proper syntax. Second, there is `fail()` for ajax request fails. Retrieve the status code there and use appropriate action. 3rd, `beforeSend()` can be used for `please wait....` in short, read the manuel. You are reinventing the wheel again.

Comment: that was I nice note @itachi thanks again. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are posting the data as "name"....

check your ajax

```
data: 'name='+name,   // this is data that is posted by ajax..you are posting it with a name as "name"
```

so u have to get the input post as "name" and not "eventname"...

either you have to rename the data's name `data: 'name='+name,` to `data: 'eventname='+name,`

**OR**

replace this

```
echo $this->test_model->check_event($this->input->post('eventname'));
```

with this

```
echo $this->test_model->check_event($this->input->post('name'));
```

in your controller and it should work....

Comment: Oh, I see, well all along I thought that I should use the name I assigned on the input declaration. Thanks for the answer. :)

Comment: go through the ajax documents and it will make you clear about these things.... :).. have fun coding....

Answer (score 2):

**It seems some error about naming, let's trace it:**

**1、Get the input:**

```
<input id="name" type="text" name="eventname" />

var name = $('#name').val();
ajax{...
data: 'name='+name,...}
```

from the code above, you give the post param 'name' valued.

**2、As it gave the post param 'name', you need replace:**

```
$this->test_model->check_event($this->input->post('eventname'));
```

**with:**

```
$this->test_model->check_event($this->input->post('name'));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no field called value in the textbox so please modify your textbox like this and try

```
<input id="name" type="text" name="eventname" value="eventname"/>
```

Now i think you will get value,please check this

Comment: He's using jquery library. Problem is, ajax param is `name` and he's accessing it as `eventname`.